# Configure github actions for email permit approval

Tags: github-actions

I am new to CI/CD, but I am aware that github workflows or just github for that matter can permit the following steps but cannot locate how to do so myself.
In short, the action should: "execute a custom script, the action then auto sends an email to specific admin users with a summary output from that script. Once admin approves of the request, the branch would continue forward in the process"

What github actions can be used to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will fits in 100% your needs but please check [environments](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-12-15-github-actions-environments-environment-protection-rules-and-environment-secrets-beta/) and required reviewers:

> The addition of environment protection rules and environment secrets enable separation of concerns between deployment and development to meet compliance and security requirements. The required reviewers environment protection rule will automatically pause a job trying to deploy to the protected environment and notifies the reviewers. Once approved, the job runs and is given secured access to the environment’s secrets. Also, the environments page includes a deployment log and information on the latest code change deployed to each environment.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that but could not figure out where within the workflow to place the environment value,

Comment: It should be on job level. I replied you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692644/how-to-reference-environment-in-github-action-workflow)