# How to reference 'environment' in github action workflow?

Tags: git, github-actions

I have the environment created named "main", but the workflow below errors out:
environment created:
[image]

Below is my github workflow:

```
name: Deploy ADf ARM    

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

environment: 
  name: main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # Checkout code
    - uses: actions/checkout@main
      ...
```

at present it notes the error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/deploy-adf-arm.yml (Line: 7, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'environment'
```

How can I reference this environment to work?

Comment: Read the docs https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env is the top level, you can only use https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment for *jobs*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It should be on job level](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment)

```yaml
name: Deploy ADf ARM    

on:
  workflow_dispatch:



jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: 
      name: main
    steps:

      # Checkout code
    - uses: actions/checkout@main
      ...
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same thing but after a specific job step?

Comment: Not using environments. Maybe there are something different solutions but I'm not aware of them. If possible split your tasks between two jobs. Then use env on the one where you expect approval.

Comment: I discovered that work around. But using environments, is there a way to pass a message from one job to another before the second has gotten started? like "these objects will be deleted", then approve and start the job?